# How to make Sphere Mask follow the parent?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph, urp

I'm making a bubble shield. I use the Sphere Mask in Shader Graph to make a collision effect (the Sphere Mask uses global position as `Coords`). But if I move the shield, the Sphere Mask will be in the same world place, so the collision effect won't work properly. How can I make the `Center` property follow the parent?

I'm using this to set the `Center`:

```
vfx.SetVector3("SphereCenter", collider.ClosestPoint(transform.position));
```